# Open Source PHP script for HTTP streaming?

Tags: php, http

Open Source PHP script for HTTP streaming?

Does anyone know something about such things?

Comment: BTW: HTTP streaming enables delivery of video-on-demand and live streaming using standard HTTP servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is built directly into PHP as of 4.3, check out [streams](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php).

Are you looking for a wrapper class?

Answer (score -1):

PHP is a bad choice for HTTP streaming.
If HTTP streaming is implemented in PHP, each streaming will occupy one thread/process in server. That doesn't scale well.